# mysql returning 1 row per id/name

Tags: python, sql, flask, jinja2, peewee

I want to join 3 tables and get the results of them without any duplicates

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.project 
INNER JOIN post on project.id = post.project_id 
INNER JOIN media on media.post_id = post.id 
;
```

Current output

[image]

I was wondering if the output could be something like

```
floaty
Headphone
fasion + technolgie
```

I tried using the distinct function. but then it only returns the names's i would like to return the joined tables, because i still want to use that data.

> models.py

I am using the Project.with_media() all

```
"""models."""
from app import db
from peewee import *
import datetime


class Project(Model):
    """Projects."""

    name = CharField(unique=True)
    content = CharField()
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today())

    class Meta(object):
        """Select database."""

        database = db

    def get_project_media(self):
        """Grab image from get_posts."""
        post = Post.select().where(Post.project_id == self).get()
        return Media.select().where(Media.post_id == post).get().media

    def check_media(self):
        """Check if project has media."""
        try:
            post = Post.select().where(Post.project_id == self).get()
            Media.select().where(Media.post_id == post.id).get()
            print('True')
            return True
        except DoesNotExist:
            print('False')
            return False
```

> This is my calling so i can display it on jinja engine

```
    def with_media():
        """Grab image from get_posts."""
        return (Project.select(Project, Post, Media)
                    .join(Post)
                    .join(Media)
                    .where(Post.id == Media.post_id
                           and
                           Project.id == Post.project_id))

    def posts(self):
        """Return all posts that are accosicated with this project."""
        return Post.select().where(Post.project_id == self)

    def media_post(self):
        """Return all posts that are accosicated with this project."""
        post = Post.select().where(Post.project_id == self)
        return post.get_media()
        # return Media.select().where(Media.post_id == post).get()



class Post(Model):
    """Model for posts."""

    project = ForeignKeyField(Project, backref='Post', null=True, default=None)
    name = CharField()
    content = TextField()
    "Media Model"
    "Category Model"
    "Project Model"
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today())

    class Meta(object):
        """Select database."""

        database = db

    def get_category(self):
        """Grab all the posts from project."""
        return (Category.select()
                .where(Category.post_id == self))

    def get_media(self):
        """Grab all media from this post."""
        return (Media.select()
                .where(Media.post_id == self))

    def standalone():
        """Return a model of all posts not bound to a project."""
        return (Post.select()
                .where(Post.project.is_null())
                .order_by(Post.created_date.desc()))

    def date():
        """Return dates order_by."""
        return(Post.select()
               .order_by(Post.created_date.desc()))


class Media(Model):
    """Media for post."""

    post = ForeignKeyField(Post, backref='Media')
    media = CharField()

    class Meta(object):
        """Select database."""

        database = db


class Category(Model):
    """model for all avaible category's."""

    post = ForeignKeyField(Post, backref='Category')
    name = CharField()

    class Meta(object):
        """Select database."""

        database = db

    def get_name():
        """Get all category's without overlaping."""
        categorys = Category.select()
        categoryList = []
        for category in categorys:
            categoryName = category.name.title()
            if categoryName not in categoryList:
                categoryList.append(categoryName)
        return categoryList


def initialize():
    """Create tables."""
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Category, Project, Post, Media], safe=True)
    db.close()
```

> main.py

**I want to call the projects with media() function so i can use the database items to call images and display content**

```
<ul class='projects'>
    {% for project in projects.with_media() %}
            {% if loop.index <= 3 %}
                <li class='project_w'>
                    <img src="{{project.media_post()}}" alt="">
                    <a href="{{url_for('project', id=project.id)}}">
                    <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class='project_h'>
                    <img src="{{project.post.media.media}}" alt="">
                    <a href="{{url_for('project', id=project.id)}}">
                    <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: why are you getting multiple rows to begin with?  I'm assuming `project.id` is unique so somewhere along the way you have multiple rows per ID but based on your results you shouldn't.  Post table schema, and relevant example rows from your tables.  Do not post images.

Comment: You'll need to edit your expected output to be the **actual** output.  You stated that you **did not** want the names by themselves.  What **do** you want?

Comment: I would like the name's with the the model media.media so that it is easier to render in jinja, i edited the example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

```
.where(Post.id == Media.post_id
                       and
                       Project.id == Post.project_id))
```

Instead of "and" you must use "&". Please see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html